# Is it possible to change object A on the client, but modify object B on the server? [Default Breeze WebApi]

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to implement something like commands in my breeze app, but I miss "*a bit of indirection*", between the model on the client and my database/EF db context.

So here is the question:
**How can I modify (create/update or delete) entity on the server, which is not one of the entities modified (created/updated/deleted) on the client?**

For example:

1. To allow user password change create a new CmdNewPassword entity (with OldPassword and NewPassword fields) on the client, but on the server check that old password is correct and update User.PasswordHash and User.PasswordSalt.

   or
2. If new Invoice entity was created on the client, create new LogEntry entity on the server to keep a log of user actions.

Save interception (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider#SaveInterception) says that entities may be added or removed from the map returned by BeforeSaveEntities, but I don't think it is possible to add anything to this map, because EntityInfo's properties have internal setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: May 8, 2013 - As of v 1.3.3, available on the Breeze website, there is a now a new public ContextProvider.CreateEntityInfo method that you should be able to call from within your BeforeSaveEntities method.

---

You are right, and you are on the right path with the idea of modifying the saveMap passed into the BeforeSaveEntities method. Currently, you can remove and modify entities from the map but you have no good way to add one.  I will try to get this fixed in the next release.

Comment: I realize it's been a week since you answered this question but:  any estimate on when we'll be able to add modified entities to the saveMap in BeforeSaveEntities?

Comment: This should be possible in the 1.3.3 release I mentioned above. Are you still having problems with it?

Comment: This gist shows what I'm trying to do. In short, increment UnitPrice of all Products in Category when you change a CategoryName.  https://gist.github.com/sugerman/d44b5ecef8108c3dcc2a  SaveChanges() is throwing an exception "same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"

Comment: Thanks for the gist, I'll try to take a look at it this evening.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to look at the gist?

Comment: Sorry Jeff, I got pulled off for another issue.  I just assigned another engineer to look at it.  My bad...

Comment: Any luck Jay?  Should I submit a report somewhere else?

Comment: N/m Jay.  Just saw the release notes for 1.3.5.  Going to give it a shot.  Thanks!